# SharePoint - Make column read only in list based on condition

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, datasheet

I have an Risk/Issue where the user selects from a drop down list if the item is an issue or a risk.

Two fields severity and probability calculate together to give a score for Risks in my list. My problem is that I've been asked is it possible to make probability read only if the user selects an issue when creating a new item.

Is this possible to enable in the datasheet view in an standard SP list?

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript/jQuery or InfoPath to customise the list form and apply business logic. This is not possible in a datasheet view.

Answer (score 0):

CSR might help you. Using JSLink you may be able to achieve this. Here is a blog, [Quick Edit supports JS Link and Client Side Rendering](https://www.spjeff.com/2014/05/17/quick-edit-supports-js-link-and-client-side-rendering/), explaining the same.

Comment: Also I found one more related answer in here http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/136936/do-not-apply-csr-override-in-quickedit-mode. It should help you with the pitfalls.